# Nvidia drivers with Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 19.04

I'm facing a strange problem I can't seem to work around.

My computer is set up with Ubuntu 19.04, with the 5.0.0-23 Linux headers and I seem to have problems installing the correct drivers for my Nvidia GTX1050.

When I purge all nvdia related packages, I manage to get a GUI but in a really small resolution (9650x540) on my laptop screen. If I plug in an external monitor in HDMI, I have the correct display on this new screen with a usual 1920*1080 resolution.

I've tried to install the nvidia-drivers with :

- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- By installing the `graphics-drivers` ppa, and running `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430` which is the latest version supporting my graphics card

When rebooting after this installation, I don't have any GUI showing up and I'm stuck with a black screen and terminal access.

I've tried setting lightdm as the default manager, or gdm3 and turning off Wayland in its conf, to no avail.

Does anyone have a clue for me ?

Comment: Update Your question with output of the command `xrandr` (with not additional monitors connected).